# how to automate bots to monitor for successful queues on orchestrator?

Tags: queue, ui-automation, monitor, uipath-orchestrator, uipath-robot

I have a project that I have to do that deals with queues being loaded successfully and unsuccessfully whereby I do manually at the moment that can be tedious and also positive negative meaning the orchestrator can state that new queues have been added but when I access the actual job (process) nothing has been added.

I would like to know, is there a way to monitor queue success and unsuccessful rates on orchestrator instead of the using monitoring it manually?

Answer (score 0):

You can access pretty much any information via the Orchestrator API.

You can find the "Orchestrator HTTP Request" activity, which will allow you to access any relevant endpoint.

Note that the provisioned Robot in Orchestrator needs to have the right access permission, so please have a look at what roles are associated to the Robot user.

The API reference can be found here:
https://docs.uipath.com/orchestrator/reference

You will see it mentions swagger, which in turn will give you all the information you need to access the relevant APIs.
[image]

Comment: Thank you so much.

Comment: Thank you! so much @Quentin  Is there a way to find this on YouTube also?

Comment: I do not think there is anything official on youtube about this particular activity.
You can have a look at the activity doc: https://docs.uipath.com/activities/docs/orchestrator-http-request
And I would also suggest looking on the forum.uipath.com in case someone shared a sample somewhere.

Comment: Thanks very much